# Angular damping on a cable segment caused by internal friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, torque, structural-beam

I'm using a physics engine to simulate a cable made of cylinder-shaped segments connected by ball socket constraints. My understanding is there will be some angular damping on the segments cause the internal friction of the cable's structural particles.

Can the resulting torque on each segment be modeled as $\tau=-c\ell\omega$ where $c$ is a constant, $\ell$ is the segment length and $\omega$ is the angular velocity? If not, how would it be modeled?

Comment: What is the reason for your model equation?